# how to apply transformation to each row that uses other rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up dataframe below:

```
col1, clo2
A,    1
A,    2
B,    3
B,    4
```

and I want to make it look like this:

```
col1, clo2
A,    1
A,    1
B,    3
B,    3
```

Basically group by `col1` and turn all values in `col2` to first value of each group, but I want to retain all rows(they have data I can't loose).

In the `R` using `dplyr` I would have done following in r to get the same result:

```
data %>% group_by(col1) %>% mutate(col2 = first(col2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `first` and `transform`(`mutate` in `R` ) in `pandas`

```
df.clo2=df.groupby('col1').clo2.transform('first')
df
Out[1024]: 
  col1  clo2
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    B     3
3    B     3
```

Comment: wow that was easy, and just because I can't tell from documentation the function that you use in transform needs to accept DataFrame or Series/NumpyArray and it should output I'm going to guess single value or same sized DataFrame/Series?

Comment: @sgp667 I think it is same size

Comment: @sgp667 yw:-) happy coding